# Can't install pywhatkit

Tags: python

I want to install the pywhatkit package, but I got an error like this:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-JBqkiU/pywhatkit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-JBqkiU/pywhatkit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-d8Zuw6
         cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-JBqkiU/pywhatkit/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-JBqkiU/pywhatkit/setup.py", line 6
        def readme() -> str:
                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What is your Python version? You seem to be using an old version of Python that does not suppory type hints.

Comment: Im use python version 3.8

Comment: Maybe because i use terminal termux

Comment: run `python --version` in this terminal, or `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.version);"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using python version 2 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/**python2**